# Visual C++ настройка проекта для чистого C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Возможно ли писать на чистом C++ в Visual C++ 2008, например?
Помогите мне с настройкой проекта. Какой нужно выбрать проект, по пунктам напишите который мог бы исключить .NET

Comment: Во-первых, почему бы не использовать более современную версию (Community версии бесплатны)? Во-вторых, а в чем действительно проблема? Опишите подробнее [mcve].

Comment: компьютер слабый очень до этого использовал vs c++ 6.0 в новых студиях не разбираюсь.

Comment: Мне кажется вы имеете ввиду win32 console application, снять все галочки...

Comment: Не надо выбирать `CLR` и тогда это с 99% вероятностью будет обычный `c++`. Там есть даже Wizard: `New Project` - `Visual C++` - `Win32` - `Win32 Console Application`. Для начала этого будет вполне достаточно.

Comment: @alexolut оформите наверное ответом.

Comment: А каким образом вообще можно .NET включить в проект C++? (только без ко-ко-ко про C++/CLI, это другой язык).

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, ну MS отдает предпочтение управляемым языкам, емнип, в VS2015 по дефолту даже нет нативного c++, надо докачивать после установки. А то, что c++/cli это уже совсем другой язык не особо явно обозначено при создании проекта. Для новичка уж точно.

Answer (score 3):

Не надо выбирать `CLR` и тогда это будет обычный `c++`. Там есть даже Wizard:

> *New Project - Visual C++ - Win32 - Win32 Console Application*.

Для начала этого будет вполне достаточно.